# Akima spline interpolation

Tags: interpolation, spline

I want to use Akima interpolation on series of points. I have those points in 3D [x, y, z]. But in all resources, I found, there is only f(x) and x (so [x,y]).
In Natrual Cubic Spline I am using this approach: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html (matrix 18) and I can calculate curve for 1, 2.. N dimension the same way... 
Is something like this possible for Akima ? Thanks...
PS: I am not math skilled, so maybe this question is totally out.. for that, I am sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

There's an original paper by Akima about this. Even though I'm not sure if he really uses 'Akima' Interpolation there, you could have a look at http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355786.

Also, there's a R package doing exactly this. You could check out the source code of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/.